# Why was a question about predictive distribution closed?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, reopen-closed

The following question [What is a predictive distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169390/what-is-a-predictive-distribution) was closed for being duplicate to this one:

[Understanding Bayesian Predictive Distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72697/understanding-bayesian-predictive-distributions)

But the last question is specifically about Bayesian predictive distributions, while the newly closed one was general, not specifically Bayesian. So it is not a duplicate, and I request that it to be reopened.

Predictive distribution is a concept that can also be treated by non-Bayesian methods!

Comment: Given the first carries the "bayesian" tag, talks about updating prior belief to posterior beiief and explicitly contains "$p(\theta|y_1,...,y_n)\propto p(y_1,...,y_n|\theta)p(\theta)$", I think it's unarguably a question about *Bayesian* predictive distributions.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @Glen_b there. But you've written a great answer on a rather neglected topic & I hope you've not been put off adding to it as promised. It's up to you of course, but if I were you I'd probably ask a new question on non-Bayesian predictive inference & put my answer there.<sup>†</sup>

Some other references (just in case you haven't already seen them):

- Lawless & Fredette (2005), "Frequentist prediction intervals and predictive distributions", *Biometrika* , **92**, 3
- Bjornstad, (1990), "Predictive Likelihood: A Review", *Statist. Sci.*, **5**, 2

† I decided to ask anyway: [What non-Bayesian methods are there for predictive inference?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/169623/17230)